# C# - ToTitleCase that only affects lower case?

Tags: c#

In C# I am looking for a code that is very similar to ToTitleCase, except I need it to ONLY affect the lower case letters. I do not want any letters that are upper case to become lower case, I only need the lower case letters to be properly brought to upper case.

This is for eCommerce software, so capitals becoming lower case is a deal breaker. Makes brand names look incorrect.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want all in uppercase and can you show what you have tried?

Comment: From what I am reading you have an input like this, "this is my COMPANY" and want the output to be, "This Is My COMPANY"  Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: The TextInfo.ToTitleCase method does not lower case already upper cased letters, at least using my current UICulture. `?textInfo.ToTitleCase("ABC Plumbing");` returns "ABC Plumbing". `?textInfo.ToTitleCase("this is ABC Plumbing");` returns
"This Is ABC Plumbing"

Answer (score 1):

You can use a method that will discard the unwanted changes from `ToTitleCase()`.

I'm using `StringBuilder` instead of a normal `string` here because  `StringBuilder` (as you can probably guess from its name) appends strings much faster than `string`'s `+=` operator. This is especially critical if your titles are long or if you use this method in a long loop, etc.

```
public string BetterTitileCase(string original)
{
    string title = /* ToTitleCase call here, etc. */;

    StringBuilder fixedTitle = new StringBuilder();

    //the title and the original string should be the same length
    for(int i = 0; i < title.length; i++)
    {
        if(char.IsLower(original[i]))
            fixedTitle.Append(title[i]);
        else
            fixedTitle.Append(original[i]);
    }

    return fixedTitle.ToString();
}
```

Comment: The `if` statement is backwards - it should be `if (original[i].IsUpper)`.

Comment: You might want to use `StringBuilder`, otherwise you are potentially creating a bunch of strings in your loop. Not good.

Comment: also, there is no instance property `IsLower` on `char`.  You probably meant: `char.IsLower(original[i])`. Did you compile your suggestion?

Comment: You should always use the `StringBuilder` example since strings are immutable, you are creating a new string each time you change fixedTitle in your first example.

Comment: I'd be tempted to forego the builder, as well, and use something like `string fixedTitle = string.Join("", title.Zip(original, (t, o) => char.IsUpper(o) ? o : t));`